# JavaScript, time zones, and daylight savings time

Tags: javascript, timezone, dst

Welcome to this week's episode of **Yet Another Time Zone Question**:

I've done a fair bit of reading on SO, tried to manipulate moment.js and date.js into helping me, and generally been plagued by a feeling of frustration since I started trying to solve this, so if someone could help or point me at the duplicate question on SO that I just haven't been able to find, that'd be awesome.

---

I have a page. This page displays a series of times, e.g.: 7:28, 7:38, 7:48. I know whether these are AM/PM. These times are always America/New York (they do not change when daylight savings time changes, as the event they correspond to always happens at that time regardless of DST). Let's call them a schedule. I want to highlight the time that is coming up next.

- This is trivial for people living in America/New York.
- This is not too terrible for people living in America/Los Angeles (assuming my logic works).

  - I can take the current time of the computer in America/Los Angeles, convert it to UTC, then determine if America/Los Angeles is currently observing DST or not and determine whether America/New York should be -0400 or -0500, apply that to the UTC, and make my comparison. This hurts a little because you're still always dealing with a Date based in America/Los Angeles and not actually changing the time zone of the Date object, but I have a reliable means of rolling back (or forward) the hours from the UTC time.

*What happens, however, when I try to determine if daylight savings time is being observed **from a computer in a region that does not observe daylight savings time at all?***

JavaScript will only create Date objects for the current time zone, to my knowledge, and then doing any determination of DST is based on that Date object.

Should I just not care? The times are primarily relevant only to people living in America/New York anyway. I'm just trying to build an application that makes sense when viewed from another time zone such that when it's 3AM in country_without_DST and it's 2PM in America/New York, the 'schedule' highlights that the 2:05PM thing is about to happen and not the 3:05AM thing.

Comment: Can you create a minimal failing example on jsfiddle that exhibits the problem behavior? A failing qunit test there would be awesome.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bBdL5/ - In order to see this phenomenon, you need to observe the page first in a timezone with DST. You will see the two offsets come back different. Then set your timezone to one that does not observe DST, quit the browser, and relaunch it. See the following two images: http://i.imgur.com/pxqIj.jpg and http://i.imgur.com/ZaXi6.jpg - I do not know of another way to determine if DST occurs than what I am showing (this is how Date.js does it)

Comment: Now that I'm building the examples, I'm thinking I could simply hard code some dates to help me determine whether it's daylight savings time or not, but should the region I want to convert to stop observing DST, that will fail without code maintenance.

Comment: That and one day in one time zone might be a different day in a different time zone (e.g.: The day before the time zone shifts in New York is the day of the time zone shift at that same time in Beijing). Not only that but it seems that even countries that both observe daylight savings time might observe them on different days (EU and US are different days in March) so the results will -still- be wrong sometimes even when calculating from within a DST-observing time zone.

Comment: I'm failing to see what the issue is here. It looks like you've shown that date.js is really good at determining the timezone offset for the local time. If you want to show a time in another timezone, consider using setTimezoneOffset?

Comment: But I don't know whether to set it to -0500 or -0400 because I don't know if America/New York is currently observing DST or not.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All comparisons with time should be done with `getTime()` of your instance. This returns the number of milliseconds since the UTC epoch. DST won't matter. You send the `getTime()` value to your server. Your clientside scripts will then convert this value back into a JavaScript `Date` object like so:

```
mydate = new Date(longmillisFromAnotherTZ);
```

Then use any method on `mydate` to display the date how you'd like. Does this make sense? I'm failing to see how there's an issue. I'd be happy to clear anything up though.

**Edit:**

Just to be 100% clear...

If two different clients need to display their actions to each other in different time zones, I'm suggesting that you use only the value from `(new Date()).getTime()` and then save that to the server. The server then sends this value to each respective client. The client is then responsible for displaying it in its own appropriate locale.

Also, if you want a library that is good for getting timezones and offsets, `getTimezoneOffset()` is known to be flakey, you should check out this library: http://www.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript

Comment: Well there is no direct server/javascript communication, but I see where you are going with this. I can indeed get the server to output its ms since UTC epoch along with the normalized-to-EST times and I can just ignore those EST times entirely and compare against what the server has hidden alongside them on the page. Is that generally what you were getting at? I don't want to misinterpret because it was difficult enough for me to convey the problem I'm having in text already :)

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying. The situation in this case is a server  displaying text on a page in EST to a client that could be anywhere. While I need to show times in EST on the page, I can definitely get UTC-since-epoch of those times -with the server- and put them in a data attribute that I can compare against with JavaScript. That should work and corresponds with your suggestion to always use getTime() and just ignore conversions between time zones entirely.

Comment: Funny, I had that same problem when I had to screen scrape a popular sports website ;p I did exactly what you present.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, I think I finally see what you're saying. You want to say something like, "The current time in NYC is **_**" based on the time that's on the user's computer, and while there's support (at least in the docs) for `setTimezone("EDT")` there doesn't appear to be support for `setTimezone("America/New York")`. You'll either have to hard code the dates for when to switch between EDT and EST (based on current time GMT, which you can get from the user's computer), or use a 3rd party API (or do this on the server side).

Comment: Definitely an excellent and concise way of explaining this problem. I'm going to give the question a bit more time before I determine what best answers the question, but both of the existing answers certainly deserve an upvote, so here those are now...