# I need to count the number of days between date applied and the date of event

Tags: javascript, date

We are designing online licensing application

I Need to calculate the no of days between the date of event and the date applied 
The date of event are Sept 16th and Dec 31st.

Java script to count number of days

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) first. Your question is lack of information, no detail, no context..

Answer (score 0):

With using the Javascript Date Object you can use the following function:

```
var firstDate = new Date("October 16, 1975 11:13:00");
var secondDate = new Date("October 14, 1975 11:13:00");


function dateDifference(start, end)
{
    return Math.round((start-end)/(1000*60*60*24));
}

alert(dateDifference(firstDate.getTime(), secondDate.getTime()));
```

Comment: This doesn't take DST into account, allthough that's not a problem in this case. You should round or floor the result though.

Comment: getTime() takes DST into account, see [JavaScript, time zones, and daylight savings time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543580/javascript-time-zones-and-daylight-savings-time)

Comment: Yeah, but not the difference between dates. `start` might be with DST and `end` without. So your result might be 19.04 or 18.96. That's why you should round it (not floor).

Comment: Hm, I can not reproduce a comma value, can you provide an example date in the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yKwF8/ ?

Comment: Dude all you have to do is cross the DST border: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/yKwF8/1/ Do you have DST where you live? If you don't, you'll not see the decimals.

Comment: Ok you are right, it should work now :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is comparing dates until they're the same. Probably a lot slower, so don't use this unless you want to extend the comparison with extra details.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/Szvfd/

```
Date.prototype.getYMD = function() {
    return this.getFullYear() + '-' + (this.getMonth()+1) + '-' + this.getDate();
};

Date.prototype.getDaysDiff = function(d2) {
    var d1 = this,
        delta = d1 < d2 ? +1 : -1;

    var days = 0;
    while (d1.getYMD() != d2.getYMD()) {
        days++;
        d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + delta);
    }
    return delta * days;
}

d1 = new Date('October 16 2012');
d2 = new Date('November 7 2012');

console.log(d1.getDaysDiff(d2)); // 22
console.log(d2.getDaysDiff(d1)); // -22
```